# Remove filter in web.xml in jetty

Tags: maven, jetty, web.xml

I have configured jetty to run my web application using the jetty maven. Jetty is supposed to be a light alternative for development and therefore it doesn't need all the stuff that is in web.xml. More specifically, I want to remove a filter in web.xml.

I tried to use the overrideDescriptor configuration property, but this only allows me to override the web.xml, not replace it. Therefore, the filter is still there.

Any ideas how I can remove the filter without modifying the original web.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no answer, I'll post my solution, which is not perfect.

```
<!-- Jetty configuration -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.5.v20120716</version>
    <configuration>
        <webApp>
            <descriptor>src/main/webapp/mock-web.xml</descriptor>
            [...]
        </webApp>
        [...]
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The downside of this approach is that you have to maintain two almost identical web.xml files. I have not found a solution that will allow me override the original web.xml file and remove a listener.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the filter-class to a PassThroughFilter in the override-web.xml:

```java
public class PassThroughFilter implements Filter{

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

---

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>OriginalFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>mypackage.PassThroughFilter</filter-class>        
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

A powerful solution would be to use 2 XML entities in your `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE document [
<!ENTITY webEntity1 SYSTEM 'webEntity1.xml'>
<!ENTITY webEntity2 SYSTEM 'webEntity2.xml'>
]>
<web-app>
    &webEntity1;
    &webEntity2;
</web-app>
```

And only 1 of them in a `custom-web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE document [
<!ENTITY webEntity1 SYSTEM 'webEntity1.xml'>
]>
<web-app>
    &webEntity1;
</web-app>
```

That way, in `webEntity1.xml` you would declare your shared servlets, filters, mappings and in `webEntity2.xml` only the filter that you don't want to use in Jetty.

Then you would configure the jetty plugin like this:

```
    <configuration>
        ...
        <webApp>
            ...
            <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/custom-web.xml</descriptor>
        </webApp>
        ...
    </configuration>
```

I just added a section to my [jetty plugin wiki page](http://www.benoitschweblin.com/2013/03/run-jetty-in-maven-life-cycle.html).

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS! You're basically utilizing a server-specific security exploit which may be fixed in a newer server version and is not necessarily present in different servers. In other words, the webapp with such a web.xml is unportable. Related issue report: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1069911